# How can I make GMail display whole email thread?

Tags: gmail

The GMail app groups together email chains in reverse chronological order.

The idea is good, but I am now missing emails. It says 10 emails in the header in the inbox, but it only shows the last 2 and I know there should be more.

Google's own mail does not allow switching off conversation view, I think? Their web mail has the same problem.

How can I see the remaining 8? Once I have opened the chain, there appears to be no buttons to press. The "..." one is not there.